# I want to print admob report in my application

Tags: ads, adsense, admob, adsense-api

I have admob account and ad units are successfully placed in my application.

now i want to print admob report in my application like User ABC has clicked '_' times in this application earning and RPM of application

how can i do that can anyone please help me on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not be possible. AdMob does have a [Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/reporting) within the larger AdSense Reporting API, but for privacy reasons it doesn't break any data down to the level of individual users. It's all aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can get most of the data with your own customization query follow this link

**https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reporting**

Very clear response from Google API's.